# Ruby: Adding a new line issues

Tags: ruby, file

I am adding new lines to a text file.

Here is the code:

```
def save_line_o_a(date, name, amount)
    open("accounts.txt","a+") do |account_file|
        account_file.write "#{date};#{name};#{amount};#{amount}; "
    end
end
```

The problem is that after each `#{amount}`, I have a new line, it is not writen on the same line:

Exemple:

```
2016-08-09 15:26:16 +0200;Original amount;450
;450
;
```

Edit (pressed enter too fast...)
Could someone explain me why it is doing this?

Comment: The `amount` from parameters is a string with a newline in it. Fix the code that generates it.

Comment: Also, you will be able to fix errors (by yourself!) much quicker if you learn a few simple tricks. Debug printing is one of them. Line debugger is another.

Comment: Completely forgot about it. But I tried to "chomp" a string with all this parameters in it, deos chomp work only for the last \n (in this case)?

Comment: yep. Read chomp's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As identified in the comments, the problem is that you have newline characters in your field values. The best solution will be to remove them (or not create them in the first place) wherever that data comes from.

If you can't do that for some reason—and since you didn't share that code with us—here's an easy way to do it after the fact:

```
def save_line_o_a(date, name, amount)
  open("accounts.txt","a+") do |account_file|
    new_line = "#{date};#{name};#{amount};#{amount}; ".tr("\n", " ")
    account_file.write(new_line)
  end
end
```

This uses [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-tr) to replace all newline (`\n`) characters in the string with a space. To delete them entirely, use `""` (an empty string) instead of `" "`.

Comment: Actually `amount` should be fixed in the caller. It is clearly meant to be something number-like.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have added a note to that effect.